why is update is not handle? (AIOGRAM)
    if Quest.quest_I == 'img/1_var_1.png':
        await state.update_data(choice=message.text)
        if message.text == '1345':
            await message.answer('Correct', reply_markup=Kb.stop_button_1)
        elif message.text != '1345' and message.text != 'Other':
            await message.answer('Incorrect', reply_markup=Kb.stop_button_1)
    elif Quest.quest_I == 'img/1_var_2.png':
        await state.update_data(choice=message.text)
        if message.text == '1325':
            await message.answer('Correct', reply_markup=Kb.stop_button_1)
        elif message.text != '1325' and message.text != 'Other':
            await message.answer('Incorrect', reply_markup=Kb.stop_button_1)
    elif Quest.quest_I == 'img/1_var_3.png':
        await state.update_data(choice=message.text)
        if message.text == '5':
            await message.answer('Correct', reply_markup=Kb.stop_button_1)
        elif message.text != '5' and message.text != 'Other':
            await message.answer('Incorrect', reply_markup=Kb.stop_button_1)


I only have a error like:
INFO:aiogram.event:Update id=83512332 is not handled. Duration 0 ms by bot
i kill 30 min and nothing changes

Do you know in which scenario you get that error? Is it on update_data statement or a message.answer statement? Is there a specific parameter that gets this error?

Honestly, I really dont know, i delete update_date and nothing change, like with message.answer
